# how to get latitude and longitude for particular landmark?

Tags: mapping, geolocation, gps, maps, latitude-longitude

how to get latitude and longitude for particular landmark/business, i would like to get lat/long for specific address how to i do that? shall i use gps device to get the lat/long?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Very recently, two or three weeks ago, Google released a new API that lets you do just what you want.

This is how it works:

```
http://maps.google.com/maps/api/geocode/format?address=some_address&sensor=true_or_false
```

And here is an example:

http://maps.google.com/maps/api/geocode/xml?address=Lenox+Hill&sensor=false

The format can be JSON or XML.

Answer (score 1):

You will need to use a Geolocation API (such as Google or Bing or Yahoo), and there might be others as well. But those are the "free" (with caveats) ones that come to mind.

Just remember they have rather strict Terms-of-use of how you can use their API, so be sure you are on the right side of the law.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc981067.aspx

http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/

Answer (score 0):

Can you elaborate a bit more on that? What type of application is that? What is the format of the landmark/business? Basically there are geo web services out there that do this kind of stuff...

Have a look at this for example:

http://www.geonames.org/maps/us-reverse-geocoder.html

http://www.geonames.org/export/ws-overview.html

Comment: already i have a address database of shops,hospitals, schools etc., now i would like to get latitude and longitude for that location

Answer (score 0):

Yahoo http://developer.yahoo.com/geo/geoplanet/guide/concepts.html

You can query for a free-form name such as address, etc, and it will return what is called a WOEID, then query the WOEID for its lat long.